# Input field goes outside parent div

Tags: html, css

```css
.searchblock {
  height: calc(4/54*100vh);
  max-height: calc(4/54*100vh);
  min-height: calc(4/54*100vh);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFD361;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.input-wrapper {
  height: 50%;
  width: calc(45/96*100%);
  margin-left: calc(2/96*100%);
}

input[type=text] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 999px;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchblock">
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="query" name="query" placeholder="  Серийный номер, название, часть слова...">
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

As result on zoom in input field goes off its parent div as if the input gains some kind of top margin when input must be in the middle of parent div (wrapper)

Normal input (no zoom in):
[image: Normal input (no zoom in)]

Zoom in:
[image: Zoom in]

Comment: I don't think your approach of calculating height etc is a good idea, at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that I use a lot of borders in parent divs, and they all must have `box-sizing:border-box` otherwise input that is not even there will go outside

My bad I showed only divs that I thought were necessary and the cause of the problem was outside of this context